# How can I extract lines of data based on different categories in one column into separate text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, extract, data-extraction

I created this script to read in a .txt file and split it into two .txt files based upon a specific word, engine. How can I extract the lines to different files based on the second column? For example, I would like the file.txt below to be separated into 7 different files.

```
file = open("file_base.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

file1 = open("file_1.txt", 'w')
file2 = open("file_2.txt", 'w')

for line in lines:
    if 'engine' in line:
        file2.write(line)
    else:
        file1.write(line)

print("All lines that contain engine have been removed from first file")
print("All lines that contain engine has been added to second file")

file.close()
file1.close()
```

file_base.text

```
Honda,engine
Honda,cooling+system
Honda,heat+&+air+conditioning
Honda,fuel+&+air
Honda,brake+&+wheel+hub
Honda,wiper+&+washer
Honda,electrical
Toyota,engine
Toyota,cooling+system
Toyota,heat+&+air+conditioning
Toyota,fuel+&+air
Toyota,brake+&+wheel+hub
Toyota,wiper+&+washer
Toyota,electrical
Ford,engine
Ford,cooling+system
Ford,heat+&+air+conditioning
Ford,fuel+&+air
Ford,brake+&+wheel+hub
Ford,wiper+&+washer
Ford,electrical
Chevrolet,engine
Chevrolet,cooling+system
Chevrolet,heat+&+air+conditioning
Chevrolet,fuel+&+air
Chevrolet,brake+&+wheel+hub
Chevrolet,wiper+&+washer
Chevrolet,electrical
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("file_base.txt", 'r') as file:
   for line in file:
      parts = line.strip().split(',')
      with open(f"{parts[1]}.txt", 'a') as file2:
         file2.write(line)
```